# Polynomial in java

Tags: java, polynomials

So after I messed with it with the help from you guys I got it to do somewhat of what I need it to do

```
public class PolynomialTestDriver {
public static void main(String[] args){
    Polynomial myPoly = new Polynomial();   
        myPoly.setCoefficient(6, 2);
        myPoly.setCoefficient(9,3);

        System.out.println(myPoly.getCoeff()+"x^"+myPoly.getDeg());

    }
}
```

however it will only print out the last myPoly.setCoefficient();
its supposed to do print out

2x^6+3x^9
but it only prints 
3x^9

Comment: It is quite unclear what you want to achieve. Do you want to write a class that can represent sparse polynomials (i.e. where most of the coefficients of the polynomial are 0)? Or a polynomial where you can set the coefficients individually? However, in the latter case the object construction should be `new Polynomial(3);`

Comment: where it says new Polynomial(3); it's supposed to indicate how many x^n there are not what the degree and coefficients are

Comment: What you've modeled here can be described more accurately as a monomial.

Comment: so how do I get it to print out the polynomial?

Comment: Why did you remove the code for the `Polynomial` class? :(

Answer (score 0):

> *"... can someone tell me where I went wrong?"*

Frankly, you probably went wrong by either 1) not reading the instructions / requirements properly before you started, or 2) not thinking carefully about what a polynomial actually is.

Hint:

Consider this polynomial in X:  3X<sup>4</sup> + 2X<sup>2</sup> + 4.

- What is the degree of the entire polynomial?
- What are the degrees of the terms?
- What are the coefficients of the terms?
- For a hypothethical polynomial of degree 4, how many terms can there be?
- If you want to represent an arbitrary polynomial as a Java class, what quantities do you actually need to store?
- How do you store them?  (Hint: simple scalar variables won't do ...)

---

Obviously, we can't see your exercises requirements, but I suspect that the `Polynomial` constructor is supposed to take the degree of the entire polynomial as a parameter, and the `setCoefficient` method is supposed to set the coefficient of the term with a given degree.